# HardDisk seeks during reads in B Tree Indexes

Tags: index, btree

B Tree Indexes are said to generally give better read performance than LSM Tree indexes. As I understand B tree indexes work by redirecting the reads to different locations on the HDD until the desired value is found, ensuring a Log(n) time complexity when the tree is balanced.

My question is regarding the redirects/pointers to locations in the harddisk. Doesn't each redirect rquire the hard disk to seek to that location before it can start reading? And isn't this an expensive operation?
 I am comparing this to the slightly poorer performing reads in LSM trees. Yes, LSM indexes have to check many files but you are mostly doing sequential reads starting from the most recent persisted segments. With a good compaction algorithm the number of files can be kept minimal. 
So the question essentially comes down to why are B Tree indexes more read performant than LSM indexes given B Tree indexes have to do random disk seeks where as LSM indexes do not? Is disk seeking not that big a performance hit as I imagine it to be?